# Why does Eclipse hang when indexing Boost and cpp-netlib headers?

Tags: eclipse, boost, eclipse-cdt, cpp-netlib

I've got both the Boost and cpp-netlib libraries installed on my Win7 machine.  In Eclipse, under my C++ project settings, I add the following include directories

```
C:\boost_1_53_0
C:\cpp-netlib-0.10.1
```

I then include the following header

```
#include <boost/network/protocol/http/client.hpp>
```

**When I go to build my project, the C++ indexer takes an hour and then finally crashes when it runs out of memory.**  However, indexing the boost header files normally takes less than a minute, and the netlib header files are trivial by comparison.

It's worth noting that both the cpp-netlib and boost directories have subdirectories named "boost", where the header files live, E.G.:

```
C:\boost_1_53_0\boost\[headers go here]
C:\cpp-netlib-0.10.1\boost\[headers go here]
```

**Why does Eclipse die?**    Is it confused by the two "boost" sub-directories?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you you have some sort of recursion in your headers.
I would try 2 things.

1. Delete all your current boost/netlib. Fetch latest and unpack.
2. Copy hpp from netlib to boost and include only boost.

As for me its working with 2 folders. Its glitches of Windows compilation. On linux this always work like charm.